# Ender 3 v2 with CR Touch/BLTouch moving down but not up

Tags: bltouch, ender3

My Ender 3 v2 with a CR Touch/BLTouch installed is only moving down, but not up!
The display shows `P Endstop` when I try to move below around halfway up the gantry. What's going on, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CR Touch/BLTouch is not connected properly. Check the cable that runs from the mainboard to the probe on both ends. It may be slightly loose, so make sure to push both ends of the cable all the way in.